# virtualbox execution error with "cannot send events to objects owned by a different thread.." message

Tags: virtualbox, qtcore, gentoo

I just upgrade my gentoo systems. Every time I upgrade Virtualbox always has a problem. 
After search related questions same as mine, I can not resolve. 
Once I execute Virtualbox, the program stops with this message.

```
nsNativeComponentLoader: autoregistering begins.
*** Registering VirtualBox_Client_Module components (all right -- a generic module!)

*** Registering VirtualBox_Server_Module components (all right -- a generic module!)

nsNativeComponentLoader: autoregistering succeeded

nNCL: registering deferred (0)

Qt FATAL: ASSERT failure in QCoreApplication::sendEvent: "Cannot send events to objects owned by a different thread. 
Current thread 0x0x55d6d5d55db0. Receiver '' (of type 'UITaskMediumEnumeration') was created in thread 0x0x55d6d5a1a4b0", file kernel/qcoreapplication.cpp, line 576

[1]    18828 abort      virtualbox
```

I understand this error caused because of the Qt version (maybe?). 
I can not figure out how to resolve it. 
I already re-emerge qt realated packages (qtcore, qtgui libxinerama opengl and all virtualbox packages) and got same error message.

Here is my result of "eix --installed virtualbox"

```
[I] app-emulation/virtualbox
     Available versions:  5.2.22 ~6.0.0 {alsa debug doc headless java libressl lvm +opengl +opus pam pax_kernel pulseaudio python +qt5 +sdk +udev vboxwebsrv vnc ELIBC="FreeBSD" KERNEL="linux" PYTHON_TARGETS="python2_7"}
     Installed versions:  5.2.22(12:17:23 AM 01/09/2019)(alsa debug opengl opus pam python qt5 sdk udev -doc -headless -java -libressl -lvm -pax_kernel -pulseaudio -vboxwebsrv -vnc ELIBC="-FreeBSD" KERNEL="linux" PYTHON_TARGETS="python2_7")
     Homepage:            https://www.virtualbox.org/
     Description:         Family of powerful x86 virtualization products for enterprise and home use

[I] app-emulation/virtualbox-additions
     Available versions:  5.2.22^m ~6.0.0^m
     Installed versions:  5.2.22^m(12:52:11 AM 01/09/2019)
     Homepage:            https://www.virtualbox.org/
     Description:         CD image containing guest additions for VirtualBox

[I] app-emulation/virtualbox-extpack-oracle
     Available versions:  5.2.22.126460^ms ~6.0.0.127566^ms
     Installed versions:  5.2.22.126460^ms(11:00:16 PM 01/08/2019)
     Homepage:            https://www.virtualbox.org/
     Description:         PUEL extensions for VirtualBox

[I] app-emulation/virtualbox-guest-additions
     Available versions:  5.2.22 ~6.0.0 {X KERNEL="linux"}
     Installed versions:  5.2.22(12:53:36 AM 01/09/2019)(X KERNEL="linux")
     Homepage:            https://www.virtualbox.org/
     Description:         VirtualBox kernel modules and user-space tools for Gentoo guests

[I] app-emulation/virtualbox-modules
     Available versions:  5.2.22 ~6.0.0 {pax_kernel KERNEL="linux"}
     Installed versions:  5.2.22(12:52:26 AM 01/09/2019)(-pax_kernel KERNEL="linux")
     Homepage:            https://www.virtualbox.org/
     Description:         Kernel Modules for Virtualbox
```

Thank you in advance, and sorry for duplicate question.